# Пул подключений и фабрика для DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, mysqlconnector

Есть долгоживущие объекты на сайте, которые с периодичностью в 4-5 минут чего-нибудь делают и пишут результаты в базу. Для себя решил что постоянно держать открытым соединение с базой излишне и наколхозил `Func<ApplicationDbContext>` предварительно зарегистрировал все это в конфигурации.

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkMySql().AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("VFL.Web").EnableRetryOnFailure());
}

services.AddTransient<Func<ApplicationDbContext>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>);
```

И работает все это с периодичным успехом выдавая иногда исключение следующего вида:

```
2019-03-28 13:03:43.2027||ERROR|VFL.Web.Filters.PermissionHandler|Permission check failed System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSectionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
   at VFL.Web.Filters.PermissionHandler.HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement) in /root/betprofit-server/VFL.Web/Filters/Permissions.cs:line 62
```

А также иногда сменяется на

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is
>   disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
>   then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
>   application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
>   context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
>   using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
>   container take care of disposing context instances. Object name:
>   'ApplicationDbContext'.

Вся работа с контекстом базы осуществляется через `using`

```
try
{

    using (var db = dbFactory())
    {
        var customer = await db.Customers.Include(c => c.Identity)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Identity.Id == userId.Value);
        if (requirement.Permissions <= customer?.ClientLevel)
            context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex, "Permission check failed");
}
```

База у меня MySQL + ASPNETCORE + EFCORE.

**Так как правильно это готовить?**

Answer (score 0):

**Внимание:Такой способ хоть и помогает избежать исключений, но приводит к [жору памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929730/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-ef-core-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5-dbcontext-pool).**

---

Необходимо зарегистрировать контекст базы следующим образом.

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkMySql().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
    }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

В таком случае на каждое новое требование зависимости будет создаваться новое соединение с базой.

Чтобы можно было переиспользовать контекст в уже в созданном экземпляре необходимо зарегистрировать такую лямбду. Полезно будет для логики, которая работает на протяжение всей жизни приложения.

```
services.AddTransient<Func<ApplicationDbContext>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>);
```

Пример использование:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Func<ApplicationDbContext> dbFactory;
    public MyClass(Func<ApplicationDbContext> dbFactory)
    {
        this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
    }
}   

// где-то внутри этого класса

using(var db = dbFactory()) 
{
    // Ваша логика
}
```