# Фабрика для EF core в режиме dbcontext pool

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

Необходимо сделать фабрику (проще лямбду конечно), которая бы выдавала свободный dbcontext из пула.

Регистрация EF выглядит так:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkMySql().AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

Регистрация лямбды так:

```
services.AddTransient<Func<ApplicationDbContext>>(s => s.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>);
```

Однако при передаче в какой-нибудь долго живущий объект, который обращается к базе по событию/таймеру получаю исключение что контекст используется уже в другом месте.

```
public class SomeService
{
    public SomeService(Func<ApplicationDbContext> dbFact)
    {
        this.dbFact = dbFact;
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        using (var db = dbFact())
        {
            // Do...
        }
    }
}
```

---

Ранее работал без пула подключений, но в результате получается так что в системе плодиться куча процессов mysql.  Если на момент старта приложения процессов около 90 в таскменеджере, то спустя сутки/двое их становится +1400. Думаю они бы и дальше размножались если бы приложение не завершалось из-за нехватки ресурсов. Открытое подключение оборачиваю в using, но видать где-то оно все равно не высвобождается.

Comment: попробуйте использовать репозиторий. а в вашем случае надо создавать каждый раз новый контекст, тогда таких проблем не будет

Comment: Для реализации репозитория мне все равно нужно будет в самом репозитории объявить контекст базы в качестве зависимости. То есть это будет та же реализация как через лямбду только в этот раз я оберну это в кастомный класс. Что поменяется?